# Accessing /etc/ipsec.conf file from PHP

Tags: php, linux, apache

I am trying to access a file `/etc/ipsec.conf` from the PHP code. The code was tested firstly on the windows server, at that moment I have given the access to `c:\abc\ipsec.conf`.
The access was given in httpd.conf in wamp using this

```
<Directory "c:/abc/">
Allow from all
Deny from none
Order allow,deny
</Directory>
```

Now when I tried testing the code in the Suse Linux I am receiving this error

```
**Warning: fopen(/etc/ipsec.conf) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /srv/www/htdocs/nsg/_ipsec.php on line 6**
```

I have given 777 permission to the `/etc` directory and also to the file. The directory `/etc` is also added to the `httpd.conf`, but still I am receiving the same error.

Comment: That's because Apache is not allowed to access files beyond his limits. That's a security risk. Not even a user can go to `/etc` without proper permissions.

Comment: Yes how to get access through please help me

Comment: @MihaiIorga that's not true. Of course accessing files under /etc is possible.

Comment: Which linux distro? Are you using SELinux or a similar layer as well? And giving 777 to /etc sounds like a really bad idea. Are you asking for trouble or is your situation that desparate? Maybe run apache as root if so (evil! - but hey it might work, right?)?

Comment: @AsifS.Abid don't use 777 for /etc. 755 (default) is just fine. ipsec.conf usually contains passwords, and that's why it have 600 or 640. At least set it to 644 (no write access for others). Probably your PHP settings (under /etc/php5 or similar) disables access to there. Or grsecurity or apparmor.

Comment: Yes thats my desperate situation hakara.

Comment: @Olli i am thinking on these lines. I am using Open Suse 11.3

Comment: @hakra well, running apache as root doesn't help a bit, if SELinux/apparmor is banning that. And making things even worse is not a good idea.

Comment: @Olli: Sure. Never do that at home. I always suggest to get in contact with a system administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As some comments point out, giving 777 to `/etc` is a bad idea.

To get access from within your php script, you should change the group (see `chown`) of the file to the same group apache/php is operating and give proper group permissions via `chmod`.  For security sakes, apache only should have access to that only file in `/etc`.

**edit** If you're using SEliunx or something similiar, this may not work. I just wanted to point out the general way to go (which is not 777-ing files).

And, of course, sanitize your inputs, prevent path traversal, and be paranoid.

**edit 2**

> Note: When safe mode is enabled, PHP checks whether the directory in 
>   which the script is operating has the same UID (owner) as the script
>   that is being executed.

So you should really make sure that, with safe-mode on, the `wwwrun` user is in the same group that owns `/etc` (WAIVING A RED FLAG ABOUT SECURITY CONCERNS HERE). Otherwise, you just apply this to the conf file you want to read-write to.

But, for satisfying security and permissions, [Apache2 suEXEC](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/suexec.html) may be the solution for you.

> The suEXEC feature provides Apache users the ability to run CGI and SSI programs under 
>   user IDs  different from the user ID of the calling web server. Normally, when a CGI or SSI 
>   program executes, it runs as the same user who is running the web server.

Sou you'd just create an independent user.

Comment: come on i want the access on the ipsec.conf file security can be tune by giving the permission as said by other and not 777ing. i want to access this file from my php script. can wwwrun user be given any right on that file? i have tried to give it but it is not working also.. :-)

Comment: if it still won't work, you should paste permissions of your ipsec.conf (`ls -l /etc/ipsec.conf`).

Answer (score 0):

I propose you to write a [SUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SUID) helper executable which changes `/etc/ipsec.conf` as required by your PHP script. Then, you PHP script could execute your SUID executable to issue the required commands.

This solution is pretty secure. Your SUID executable could make sure only authorized changes are being done to `ipsec.conf`, which adds another layer between your webserver and the critical file.

If you are careful, you could write the helper executable in PHP. In this case you would have to use `sudo` (and configure `/etc/sudoers` accordingly) as script cannot be directly made SUID.

Comment: i will try this tommorow as don't have the system in home. and will tell you as it goes thanks